# Some Pandas' operation (such as interpolate) doesn't support its nullable integer type

Tags: python, pandas

As of Pandas 0.25.1, there exists a nullable integer type. However, I found that some functionality is missing. The example below shows how nullable integer can be used in basic point-wise arithmetics but can not be used in linear interpolation. The interpolation function seems to treat `pd.Int64Dtype()` as if it is generic `object` dtype.

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, 3])
u = s.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
print(s)
print(s.interpolate())
print(u)
print(s+100)
print(u+100)
print(s*u)
try:
    print(u.interpolate())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print(u.interpolate(method='ffill'))
```

Output:

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    3.0
dtype: float64
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
0      0
1      1
2    NaN
3      3
dtype: Int64
0    100.0
1    101.0
2      NaN
3    103.0
dtype: float64
0    100
1    101
2    NaN
3    103
dtype: Int64
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    9.0
dtype: float64
Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill) or backfill (bfill). Got linear
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    3
dtype: Int64
```

What I expect as an answer:

- An explanation of this behaviour --- maybe a rationale for deliberate design decision, or a bug report.
- OR an as comprehensive as possible a list of things most would expect of nullable int type but currently doesn't have support for.
- OR some strategy to avoid unexpected bugs if you want to use nullable int types. Because, for example, that error message seen above is not exactly helpful.